# How to write mock test case for the controller inn java

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

This is my controller class

```
@Controller
public class myClass extends BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/myList", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody MyBaseVO getMyList(@RequestBody MyBaseVO requestObj) throws Exception {
        requestObj.setEntity(getConfig(LanguageConstant.MY_MODULE_ID));
        MyBaseVO response = (MyBaseVO) this.execute(requestObj,LanguageConstant.MY_MODULE_ID);
        return response;
    }

}
```

I wanted to write a mock test case but stuck at this point, also i'm not sure i am doing correct or not. Can anyone help me in this.

```
public class myClassTest{

    myClass spy = Mockito.spy(new myClass ());
    Mockito.when(spy.getMyList(itemRequest)).thenReturn(itemReq);
}
```

I am not sure how to use url `myList` in testcase and request and response object. I have created a json file of my request and response. Since it is using parent class therefore I am using spy for my testcase.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Spring, you should have a look at Spring's platform Mock Test implementation for Spring MVC.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework